# Which contraceptives are vegan?

Tags: veganism, health, is-it-vegan, medicine

There exists a wide range of methods for contraception. Some are obvious vegan (e.g. [NFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_family_planning)), while others clearly aren't (e.g. [birth control pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_oral_contraceptive_pill) containing lactose). Which contraceptives are vegan?

(There exists a similar question [Why are some condoms not vegan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/533/why-are-some-condoms-not-vegan), which only covers condoms.)

Answer (score 12):

Methods that appear to be reliably vegan:

- **Rhythm method** (tracking menstrual cycle to avoid intercourse around ovulation)
- **Withdrawal** (avoiding ejaculation in/on the vagina)
- **Sterilization** (tubal ligation or vasectomy)
- A copper **IUD** (intrauterine device), although investigation into whether a particular company or IUD used animal testing would be advisable
- *Some* **condoms** (also see [this more detailed question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/533/why-are-some-condoms-not-vegan))

(Note that you are advised to research into the effectiveness of each method on your own.)

Comment: While withdrawing may be reliably _vegan_, withdrawing is [not especially effective](http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/withdrawal-method/basics/definition/prc-20020661) as a method of birth control.

Comment: Even rhythm, or condoms, or ultimately [even sterilization](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4137647/) has possible failure rates -- regardless of one's vegan status, investigating reliability of contraceptive techniques is highly advisable. But that's sort of outside the scope of the question (vegans aren't less susceptible to pregnancy when practicing withdrawl, e.g.) :)

Comment: All contraceptive methods indeed have failure rates, no one method is perfect. My comment was based on my false belief that withdrawal is much worse than all others (and thus that specifically withdrawal is undesirable to even mention in any type of advice). In fact, withdrawal is [about as in-effective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_birth_control_methods#Effectiveness) as using a male condom — which is a rather shocking revelation to me.

Comment: @Zsub, withdrawal and condoms are both unsafe if used incorrectly. But using a condom safely is _much_ easier and more realistic than using withdrawal correctly (not to say that it is more satisfying). I'll go as far and say that the number on wikipedia in the column "Perfect-use failure rate" is completely irrelevant for withdrawal, whereas it is realistic to use a condom perfectly (by choosing the right size, rolling it up completely and removing the air from the tip).

Comment: Withdrawal is probably ineffective for many men because of [Pre-ejaculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-ejaculate) (NSFW!).